# ASP.NET Add cell to Gridview row with string from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview, code-behind

I have a gridview display results from a LINQ query.

I want to add a column at the end that has a link. The issue is the link is dynamically generated in my code behind. I am not sure how to get this to the main page.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you paste your linq query here.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [`OnRowDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onrowdatabound.aspx) event, you can use this event to create your link and insert it into the last cell.  It will be fired each time a row is created and bound to a data item.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column to the GridView during PageLoad or some other event that fires once. You can then set the content of that column using it's RowDataBound function by using some thing a long these lines, where 0 is the index of the column:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "*** results from your LINQ Query ****"
}
```